# Determining what to multiply each number in a set by so that their sum equals 100?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages, mathematical-astronomy

According to [this astronomy webpage](http://www.atlasoftheuniverse.com/startype.html), there are many types of stars. I am a programmer, and I want use procedural generation to create a galaxy with only non-giant, main-sequence stars. Those are the A, F, G, K, and M type stars. However, while the image on the webpage shows their rate of abundance, I can't just use that by itself, since the sum of their rates of occurrence is not equal to 100. I also want each type of star included to remain at the same rate of occurrence relative to the others.

$$0.7 + 2  + 3.5 + 8 + 80 = 94.2$$

I want to find what number I can multiply each by so that their sum equals $100$.

In other words, I need to solve the below equation for $x$.

$$0.7x + 2x  + 3.5x + 8x + 80x = 100$$

How can I find out what $x$ is?

Comment: So you have $94.2x=100$.  One can sum up $ax+bx=(a+b)x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the distributive law to write your equation as 
$$x(0.7 + 2  + 3.5 + 8 + 80) = 100\\94.2x=100\\x=\frac{100}{94.2}\approx 1.06157$$